# Имя собственное после прилагательного. Инверсия?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Вот пример комментария к видео:

> Шикарный Сергей Пархоменко. И нет никаких двух Сергеев Пархоменко. Напротив, он очень органичен.

Шикарный Сергей Пархоменко -- это двусоставное предложение с инверсией? Возможны ли здесь другие трактовки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе возможны **два варианта**:  двусоставное предложение   и номинативное предложение. В приведенном **контексте** это номинативное предложение.

**Вариант 1. Двусоставное предложение** с инверсией сказуемого, **ударение** падает на сказуемое.

***ШикАрный Сергей Пахоменко.***

Контекст. Показывают кадры с **разным** имиджем, комментарий дается для каждого кадра. *(Вот) простовАтый парень. (Вот) шикАрный Сергей Пахоменко.*

**Вариант 2. Номинативное предложение**  с определением, **ударение** падает на  имя (предмет).  Могут показывать кадры с разным имиджем, но ведущий видит его основное качество. И считает, что это  постоянное определение его личности.

***Шикарный Сергей ПахОменко.***  И нет никаких двух Сергеев Пархоменко. Напротив, он очень органичен.

Приложение

[Назывное предложение или инверсия?](http://russkiepravila.ru/vidy-prostogo-predlozheniya-po-strukture-vopros-1.html)

Бывают, однако, случаи, когда в личном предложении сказуемое-прилагательное стоит перед подлежащим, и наоборот: в назывном предложении определение-прилагательное следует за именем существительным.

Сравним для примера:

1) ***Поздняя осень***. Грачи улетели (Некрасов);

2) ***Славная осень***! Здоровый, ядрёный воздух усталые силы бодрит (Некрасов).

Если взять выделенные сочетания слов вне контекста, то установить, какое из них является назывным предложением, а какое — двусоставным со сказуемым-прилагательным, невозможно.

В контексте же выясняется, что во втором примере ***славная*** — сказуемое; это вытекает из содержания следующего предложения, подтверждающего, что осень действительно славная.

Иначе воспринимается предложение ***Поздняя осень***, в котором утверждается существование того, что названо существительным в форме именительного падежа. Это назывное предложение.

Comment: Полные прилагательные могут являться сказуемыми, когда они стоят после подлежащего. Перед сказуемым они являются определениями. Людмила права, порядок слов имеет значение.

Comment: Может быть, и права, а может, и нет. Чтобы судить об этом, надо очень хорошо знать тему. Но на всякий случай  я добавила  в свой ответ материал с ДРУГОЙ точкой зрения.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно справочнику по подготовке к ЕГЭ, это односоставное номинативное предложение. Там приводится такой пример односоставных предложений:

> «Славная осень. Морозные ночи. Тихие, ясные дни» (Некрасов);

То, что это имя собственное, ничего не определяет. Рассказ о чем-либо, особенно в формате репортажа, часто начинается с номинатива - основного объекта репортажа, с прилагательным или без:

> Архангельск. Впервые я побывал тут в 2000 году.
>
> Холодный Архангельск. Впервые я побывал тут в 2000 году.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сказала, что это именительный темы (именительный представления): его назвали, а потом дали ему характеристику.

Собственно, инверсией в двусоставном предложении это не может быть, потому что порядок слов как раз и определяет тип предложения.

Шикарный Сергей Пархоменко.- номинативное.

Сергей Пархоменко шикарный. - двусоставное, но тогда здесь чего-то не хватает. Сергей Пархоменко - шикарный (артист).

Вот если бы прилагательное было краткое, тогда возможна была бы инверсия сказуемого: Шикарен Сергей Пархоменко.